# Color points according to their contour color

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to color a point according to the colormap used by the `contour` function? 
I realize that I can specify a colormap, but presumably the `contour` function does some
scaling and/or normalization of the data?

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss

def plot_2d_probsurface(data, resolution=20, ax = None, xlim=None, ylim=None):
    # create a function to calcualte the density at a particular location
    kde = ss.gaussian_kde(data.T)

    # calculate the limits if there are no values passed in
    # passed in values are useful if calling this function
    # systematically with different sets of data whose limits
    # aren't consistent
    if xlim is None:
        xlim = (min(data[:,0]), max(data[:,0]))

    if ylim is None:
        ylim = (min(data[:,1]), max(data[:,1]))

    # create some tick marks that will be used to create a grid
    xs = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], resolution)
    ys = np.linspace(ylim[0], ylim[1], resolution)

    # wrap the KDE function and vectorize it so that we can call it on
    # the entire grid at once
    def calc_prob(x,y):
        return kde([x,y])[0]
    calc_prob = vectorize(calc_prob)

    # check if we've received a plotting surface
    if ax is None:
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    # create the grid and calculate the density at each point
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)
    Z = calc_prob(X,Y) 

    # the values according to which the points should be colored
    point_values = kde(data.T)

    # plot the contour
    cont = ax.contour(X,Y,Z)
    #print cont
    ax.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], 'o')

    return (None, None)

data_x = np.random.random((50,2))
cont = plot_2d_probsurface(data_x)
```

So in the plot below, the points with the highest density would be colored brown, the next orange, the next yellow, etc... The values according to which the points should be colored are already in `point_values`. This just needs to be converted to colors and passed to the `plot` function. But how do I scale them like in the `contour` plot?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be as simple as changing `plot` to `scatter` and passing the point values as the `c=point_values` parameter:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss

def plot_2d_probsurface(data, resolution=20, ax = None, xlim=None, ylim=None):
    # create a function to calcualte the density at a particular location
    kde = ss.gaussian_kde(data.T)

    # calculate the limits if there are no values passed in
    # passed in values are useful if calling this function
    # systematically with different sets of data whose limits
    # aren't consistent
    if xlim is None:
        xlim = (min(data[:,0]), max(data[:,0]))

    if ylim is None:
        ylim = (min(data[:,1]), max(data[:,1]))

    # create some tick marks that will be used to create a grid
    xs = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], resolution)
    ys = np.linspace(ylim[0], ylim[1], resolution)

    # wrap the KDE function and vectorize it so that we can call it on
    # the entire grid at once
    def calc_prob(x,y):
        return kde([x,y])[0]
    calc_prob = vectorize(calc_prob)

    # check if we've received a plotting surface
    if ax is None:
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    # create the grid and calculate the density at each point
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)
    Z = calc_prob(X,Y) 

    # plot the contour
    cont = ax.contour(X,Y,Z)
    point_values = kde(data.T)
    print point_values
    #print cont
    ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=point_values)

    return (None, None)

data_x = np.random.random((50,2))
cont = plot_2d_probsurface(data_x)
```

With this outcome:

[image]

Comment: Kudos for answering your own question! Just FYI: The colors won't exactly match.  The colors for the contours are being scaled to the min and max contour, while the scatter colors are being scaled to the min and max of the data.  A quick way around this is to do something similar to `cont = ax.contour(...)` and then `ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap=cont.cmap, norm=cont.norm)`.  This will give a continuous, rather than discrete (as `contourf` would use) colormap, but the scaling will be the same.  (If you really need a discrete colormap, use `plt.get_cmap("name", N)`.)

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly what I was asking about. If you want to formulate that as an answer, I'll accept it since it's a more correct and precise answer to the question I asked :)